# Rename object url in video HTML5

Tags: html, angular, video, download, blob

I have a blob coming from my controller, and I'm using this for video player in HTML5. The only problem is when I click on download, I get the blob name as name of the file, and I would give a custom name.

That's my code:

Component:

```
  this._helpService.GetMediaVideo(true, this.helplabels._VIDEO_1).subscribe(
    data => {
      this.videoInd1 = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(URL.createObjectURL(data));
    });
```

HTML:

```
<video class='center' [src]="this.videoInd1" controls controlsList="" preload="auto"></video>
```

So, when people click on download, the file name should be something custom instead of the blob name created with createObjectURL.

Comment: I answered my own question after I found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was easier then I thought. Just add the title to video like that:

```
<video class='center' title="My Video" [src]="this.videoInd1" controls controlsList="" preload="auto"></video>
```